# JSON doesn't fill the backbone collection directly

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have JSON that is returned from the server, and I'm populating a Backbone collection with it.

#### Models

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

});

PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});
```

#### The JSON for example-

```
var jsonString = "[
  { \"name\": \"Anna\", \"id\": 5 },
  { \"name\": \"Lina\", \"id\": 26 },
  { \"name\": \"Melissa\", \"id\": 55 }    
]"

var people = JSON.parse(jsonString); //people is now an array of 3 persons
```

#### Works:

```
var personCollection = new PersonCollection();
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    personCollection.add(people[i]);
}
var personCollectionView = new PersonCollectionView({ collection:  personCollection});
```

#### Doesn't work :(

```
var personCollectionView = new PersonCollectionView({ collection:  people});
```

My JSON is returning an array of models, I'm not sure why I can't pass this array directly to the PersonCollectionView? Is there something I need to do in the parse method of PersonCollection, such that when given an array of models, it will convert it into a collection of models?

I'm sure I'm missing something. Can someone point out what that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not creating correctly your collection object, remove the `new` keyword as:

```
PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});
```

Then you can create your JSON object and pass it to the collection:

```
var people = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var personCollection = new PersonCollection(people);
```

Notice that `JSON.parse` is with lowercase and `jsonString` has an incorrect syntax:

```
var jsonString = "[  { \"name\": \"Anna\", \"id\": 5 },  { \"name\": \"Lina\", \"id\": 26 },   { \"name\": \"Melissa\", \"id\": 55 }    ]";
```

See a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dqywu/).

Comment: Apologies @JonathanNaguin, the new keyword and "Parse" were typos. I tried initializing the personCollection like you suggested, didn't work though.

Comment: @neuDev33 Notice too that `jsonString` is wrong, the string should be in the same line... See the demo

Comment: is there any way to do this within the PersonCollection or PersonCollectionView, in the initialize/parse methods?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, `people` isn't a proper Backbone collection (unless you've omitted the code where it is defined). If it's just a JSON array, create the collection first

```
var personCollection = new PersonCollection(people);
```

Then use that Collection when you create the view

```
var personCollectionView = new PersonCollectionView({collection: personCollection});
```